# How to install RPM Fusion repository with Ansible on Fedora 32 Server virtual machine?

Tags: ansible, fedora, rpm, repository, ansible-playbook

I want to install RPM Fusion repository on Fedora 32 Server virtual machine with Ansible

I've tried various possibility unsuccessfully :

```
- name: Enable the RPM Fusion repository
command: dnf install https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-    free-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm
when: ansible_facts['os_family'] == 'Fedora' and ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] == '32'
```

or

```
- name: Enable the RPM Fusion repository
  dnf:
    name: 'https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-    free-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm'
    state: present
  when: ansible_facts['os_family'] == 'Fedora' and ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] == '32'
```

---

Every time the task is skipped

```
TASK [Enable the RPM Fusion repository] *******************************************************************************
skipping: [my-ip-address]
```

Do you have an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `command` to install packages. This has no hope of idempotence and will fail in various and subtle ways.

The reason these are skipped is that the `os_family` fact is never `Fedora`. It is set to `RedHat` on Fedora systems.

You should be checking for the distribution name directly:

```
when: ansible_distribution == 'Fedora' and ansible_distribution_major_version|int == 32
```

---

You've got further problems, though, and your `dnf` play will also fail, because you tried to use a shell substitution and Ansible won't do anything with that.

Your play should look more like this:

```
- name: Enable the RPM Fusion repository
  dnf:
    name: "https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-{{ansible_distribution_major_version}}.noarch.rpm"
    state: present
  when: ansible_distribution == 'Fedora'
```

We're actually providing the version number via substitution, so it will have "32" instead of a random shell command. And of course in this case there is no need to check the distribution version in `when:` because the relevant version is already provided in the package name.

Comment: Thanks! Michael it's working very well

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot. I am new to the whole world of Linux so I hope you don't mind me asking, but what is the difference between the `when: ansible_distribution == 'Fedora'` and `when: ansible_distribution == 'Fedora' and ansible_distribution_major_version|int == 32` (I'm assuming `32` is 32-bit)?

Comment: @telometto No more than 33 is 33-bit or 34 is 34-bit. As it says, it is checking the distro version.